# Translation Concept for Fundamental NGX Applications

Tags: angular, internationalization, sap-fiori

I would like to implement an application with Angular and [Fundamental NGX](https://sap.github.io/fundamental-ngx/#/core/home).

However, **I am not sure about the translation concept for such applications**.

So far, I have found the following information:

- [Angular's documentation for i18n](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview)

  - If I understand correctly, different artifacts seem to be built and deployed

    for every supported language.
- [Fundamental NGX's documentation for i18n](https://sap.github.io/fundamental-ngx/#/platform/i18n)

  - If I understand correctly, this approach seems to make use of pipes for translating during runtime.

Based on this information, I have two questions:

1. **As an application developer, does it make sense to follow the i18n approach which Angular documents?**
2. **How can I change the language of Fundamental NGX during runtime? (I did see the example in the documentation, but the 'code block' seems to be broken.)**

I have looked into the documentation for Angular and Fundamental NGX.
I expected to see a common approach to translation. Instead, I saw two different approaches and am wondering how to proceed.
In addition, I saw a small issue with the Fundamental NGX i18n documentation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.